# How to read PDF files which are in asian languages (Chinese, Japanese, Thai, etc.) and store in a string in python

Tags: python, unicode, nlp, text-extraction, pdf-reader

I am using PyPDF2 to read PDF files in python. While it works well for languages in English and European languages (with alphabets in english), the library fails to read Asian languages like Japanese and Chinese. I tried `encode('utf-8')`, `decode('utf-8')` but nothing seems to work. It just prints a blank string on extraction of the text.

I have tried other libraries like textract and PDFMiner but no success yet.

When I copy the text from PDF and paste it on a notebook, the characters turn into some random format text (probably in a different encoding).

```
def convert_pdf_to_text(filename):
    text = ''
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(filename, "rb"))
    if pdf.isEncrypted:
        pdf.decrypt('')
    for page in pdf.pages:
        text = text + page.extractText()
    return text
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The code you show seems ok. Probably, there's either a problem with how the PDF encodes the text, or a bug in the library. There's an [open issue on Github](https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/252) that might be related to your problem.

Comment: Can you provide a sample PDF? I can think of some possible causes but it's hard to say without more info.

Comment: Here is the link to a PDF in Japanese - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OUO4XnbTcWgQdWZe59QUqEOnKVNDEJqv

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I too faced similar issue. I could resolve it by using 'tika-python' library.

```
import tika
tika.initVM()
from tika import parser
parsed = parser.from_file('fileName.pdf')
print(parsed["metadata"])
print(parsed["content"])
```

You can find more information about the library over [here](https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python)

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: what does tika.initVM() do?