# Extract text from pdf file with Python

Tags: python, pdf, text-extraction

I would like to extract text, including tables from pdf file.

I tried `camelot`, but it can only get table data not text.

I also tried `PDF2`, however it can't read Chinese characters.

Here is the [pdf sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fXLxVqmHqn_TCqmfaEbmZPOvrQl9e1-B) to read.

Are there any recommended text-extraction python packages?

Comment: [pdfminer.six](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pdfminer.six/files) from `conda-forge` is pretty good, go to the files tab and grab the tarball that matches your system (windows, linux, mac)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985619/how-to-read-pdf-files-which-are-in-asian-languages-chinese-japanese-thai-etc

Comment: There is a Python wrapper for PDFNet here https://github.com/PDFTron/PDFNetWrappers
online demo is here https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-tools/pdf-table-extraction/

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest way is to extract text in one OS shell command line using the poppler pdf utility tools (often included in python libraries) then modify that output in python.py as required.

`>pdftotext -layout -f 1 -l 1 -enc UTF-8 sample.pdf`

NOTE some of the text is embeded to right of the logo image and that can be extracted separately using `pdftoppm -png` or `pdfimages` then pass to inferior output quality OCR tools for those smaller areas.

[image]